# How to add easing to image switching

Tags: jquery

I've been using some jQuery code which I came across online that switches (toggles) images on clicking. It works well. I'm using it on a webpage with a small and large image. I would like to ease the transition between the two, it's too abrupt.  I've tried to get jQuery animate to work without success. If possible, I would like to use the easeOutCubic function. Html:

```
    <img id="intro_pic1" class="img-swap" src="/templates/beez_20/images/e2tw/books/wiw/wiw01/pic1_off.png" align="left">
```

jQuery:

```
      jQuery(".img-swap").on('click', function() {
        if (jQuery(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");        
        } else {
          this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("on");
      });
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove below if condition, because you have used jQuery selector for img-swap and checking for the same.

```
if (jQuery(this).attr("class") == "img-swap") {
```

You can try this:

```
$(".img-swap").click(function() {
    var newSRC = 'off';
    var oldSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    //change src image here
    if(oldSRC.indexOf(newSRC)!=-1)
    {
         newSRC = oldSRC.replace('off','on');
    }

    $(this).slideToggle(
        3000, 
        'easeOutCubic',function(){
         $(this).attr('src',newSRC);
             $(this).slideToggle(
        3000, 
        'easeOutCubic');
     });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kJZxQ/350/)**

**Note** - I have overridden easeOutCubic function in jsfiddle as I could not load required library.

Comment: The image switch works on the first click but subsequent clicks do not return to the initial image, all that happens is that the second image cycles thru fade/refade. Also, I'm not much into the fade effect, I would prefer an easing effect. Thanks

Comment: I loaded in your new code, thanks. But there is still a problem. The sequence goes like this, small image is clicked, and is replaced by the larger image, but this replacement process is not smooth with a jump to full size towards the end of the display. Next, when the large image is clicked, it is replaced not by the smaller image but by an empty "placemarker". If this is, in turn, clicked it goes into a repetitive 'easeOutCubic' cycle and the larger image is not displayed. I would have thought that the new code would have worked like your jsfiddle example (thank you for that).